# Error with modules gumdrop-cli.ts metaplex

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft, metaplex, cryptocurrency-airdrop

I've been testing metaplex and wanted to try testing gumdrop, I downloaded the gumdrop repo from here https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/gumdrop/ and tried running it but it didn't work. I then placed it inside the original metaplex folder (~/metaplex/js/packages/gumdrop) as I thought that would maybe fix it but I now run into this error:

C:\Users\Shady\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:843
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
~/metaplex/js/packages/gumdrop/packages/cli/src/gumdrop-cli.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"commander"' has no exported member 'program'.

4 import { program } from 'commander';
~~~~~~~
~/metaplex/js/packages/gumdrop/packages/cli/src/gumdrop-cli.ts:11:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-sesv2' or its corresponding type declarations.

11 } from '@aws-sdk/client-sesv2';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~/metaplex/js/packages/gumdrop/packages/cli/src/gumdrop-cli.ts:13:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'discord.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

13 import * as discord from 'discord.js';

Answer (score 0):

copying the repo into the old location is not correct. It only causes those package issues that you saw.

To make the gumdrop cli work you

1. need to have yarn installed.
2. Should run yarn install in the packages/cli folder
3. Run the cli with ts-node